# Typescript Cannot find offscreencanvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, three.js

I am attempting to move a Three.js project to TypeScript. When I tried top compile it I would get an error referenced in this issue on the Three.js repo:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/17698

Following those steps I installed `@types/offscreencanvas` as well as edited my tsconfig.json, but now I get this output when trying to run `tsc`:

```
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(16,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasState'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(16,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasTransform'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(16,83): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasCompositing'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(17,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasImageSmoothing'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(17,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasFillStrokeStyles'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(17,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasShadowStyles'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(17,71): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasFilters'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(17,86): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasRect'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(17,98): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasDrawPath'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(18,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasText'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(18,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasImageData'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(18,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasPathDrawingStyles'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(18,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasTextDrawingStyles'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(18,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasPath'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(34,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(36,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ImageBitmapRenderingContext'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(49,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasImageSource'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(51,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasImageSource'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(53,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasImageSource'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(58,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ImageBitmapSource'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(59,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ImageBitmapSource'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(64,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transferable'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(68,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transferable'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(72,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transferable'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(76,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(76,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WindowEventHandlers'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(77,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transferable'.
node_modules/@types/offscreencanvas/index.d.ts(80,83): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transferable'.
node_modules/three/src/renderers/webvr/WebVRManager.d.ts(13,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
node_modules/three/src/renderers/webvr/WebVRManager.d.ts(14,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'VRDisplay'.
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{...
    "dependencies": {
    "@types/webgl2": "0.0.5",
    "offscreen-canvas": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@types/gsap": "^1.20.2",
    "@types/offscreencanvas": "^2019.6.1",
    "@types/three": "^0.103.2",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "browserify": "^16.5.0",
    "fancy-log": "^1.3.3",
    "gsap": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-tap": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "gulp-uglify-es": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "three": "^0.110.0",
    "tsify": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

and my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "types": ["webgl2", "offscreencanvas"],
        "lib": [
            "ES2016",
            "DOM",
            "ES2015",
            "ES2015.Iterable"
        ],
        "outDir": "dist/js/projects"
    },
    "file": [
        "src/js/projects/main.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does your typescript code that import these look like?

Comment: Here is the entry file https://github.com/PickleProgramming/tesseract/blob/master/src/js/projects/tesseract/main.ts.
The whole project is pretty massive and is only going to get bigger. You think that the issue could be in the .ts file and not my configuration? If that's the case I think I would rather just use TS elsewhere and keep writing my Three.js project in regular JS.

Comment: I think it is most likely a config issue.

Comment: Are you running `tsc` from terminal, or from a script inside `package.json`? it seems as this might be a typescript version issue. If you are running from terminal the TS version might be different than what is installed in the repo.

Comment: Ah yes, I think that was it! I can finish compilation without errors now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As per my comment to your question*

This seems to be a TypeScript version problem, but the version in your `package.json` seems to be correct. Have you tried to run this from a `script` within your `package.json`, in stead of through your terminal?

```
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
     //...
  },
  //...
}
```

Then you can run `npm run build` or `yarn build`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Pixi.js and for me installing @types/offscreencanvas did not help. So I copied definitions from it and pasted them into main.d.ts to fix.

But be warned that definitions can become outdated at some point if you do that. I did that since I use Lerna monorepo + Angular, so it was hard for me to keep track of a problem, could not find any other solution sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/issues/1909,  I fixed the issue by adding
`"types": ["jasmine","offscreencanvas"]` in tsconfig file